# Finding global maxima and global minima

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I get the global maxima and minima for this function

$$ k(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}  \text{with domain } \mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and your function is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ you can differentiate and see at what points it becomes zero. Those are your critical points because there are no points where the derivative is undefined for this function. Then you will find all critical points where the derivative is zero and plug in those points to see which ones give the highest and lowest values among all of the critical points you have.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $k(1) = \frac{1}{2}$, $k(-1) = -k(1)$, and $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} k(x) = 0$. Then the set $\{ x | |k(x) \ge k(1) \}$ is bounded. Since $k$ is continuous, the set is compact, hence $k$ has a global maximum and minimum.

Since $k$ is differentiable, we can set $k'(x) = 0$ to look for solutions. This gives $k'(x) = - \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2+1)^2} = 0$, which gives $x = \pm 1$. Since there is a global maximum and a global minimum, they must be at these points, hence we see that $\sup_x k(x) = \frac{1}{2}$, $\inf_x k(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, how is the numerator is $ (x+1)(x-1) $ when i got the derivative i had $ \frac{(x)'\cdot(x^2+1)-(x)\cdot(x^2+1)'}{(x^2+1)^2} $ so i have $ \frac{-(x)(2x)}{(x^2+1)^2}$

Comment: Numerator should be $1-x^2$..may be a typo !

Comment: What's wrong with my derivative? Did i do something wrong with the quotient rule ?

Comment: @Tennisman you are applying D on wrong terms, check division rule again.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. I took the derivative of numerator times the denominator minus the numerator times the derivative of the denominator all that divided by the $(denominator)^2$ so what's wrong ?

Comment: The derivative above is correct. It is just the standard quotient rule. $(1+x^2)-2 x^2 = 1-x^2 = (1-x)(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

observe that for $x = 0$ your function is $0$, for $x \not= 0$ you have 
$$\frac{|x|}{x^2 + 1} \leq \frac{|x|}{2|x|}$$ by the aritmethic-geometric mean inequality. Therefore $|k(x)| \leq 1/2$ hence 
$$ - \frac{1}{2} \leq k(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
there is equality in the AM GM inequality only for the terms being equal hence for $x^2 = 1$ which gives us $x = 1$ or $x= -1$. plugging those $x$'s into $k$ tells you that $k$ obtains the values plus and minus $\frac{1}{2}$ hence those are its extremas

Answer (score 0):

$k(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. We have $k(0)=\lim_{x\to\infty}k(x)=0$. When $x>0$, using the inequality $a+b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$ for positive $a$ and $b$, $$k(x)=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x \cdot \frac{1}{x}}} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Similarly, when $x<0$, $k(x) \geq -\frac{1}{2}$. Then you know the global maxima and minima. They can be achieved when $x=1$ and $x=-1$.